# java generic template error

Tags: java, generics

Why do i get a compilation error on eclipse with the following definition in an interface:
Area is an interface.

```
public interface Shape {
     ...  
     public Comparator<T extends Area> getComparator();
}
```

and not if I use instead:

```
public interface Shape {
     ... 
     public Comparator<? extends Area> getComparator();
}
```

Comment: `Comparator<? extends Area>` is pretty useless; you can't use it to compare anything

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because the compiler has no idea what `T` is supposed to be or represent.  Now, if you had something like `public interface Shape<T>` as the interface declaration, we could probably get something to work with that.

Comment: Oh right! But if I do not want consistency but just a condition that the Comparator should be for a class that implements an interface then <? extends Area> should be alright? Also, is it frowned upon - using ? in generics?

Comment: @CaptainJacksparrow that's correct, and no, there's nothing wrong with using `?` in generics.

Answer (score 3):

T isn't defined in the code sample you've shown.

The following should be legal:

```
public interface Shape {
     ...  
     public <T extends Area> Comparator<T> getComparator();
}
```

or:

```
public interface Shape<T extends Area> {
     ...  
     public Comparator<T> getComparator();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The first method is going to return an object based on a parameter, if its class extends the `Area` class.

The second method doesn't have to wait on a parameter to get a type.

To get the first one to work, either infer generics on the interface:

```
public interface Shape<T extends Area>
```

or parameterize the method:

```
public <T extends Area> Comparator<T> getComparator();
```

The compiler needs to know what T can be, and T is based off of a definition either in a parameter or a construction with an inferred generic.